# Post HTTP data error

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, networking, httprequest

```
    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&nbr=%@&import=%@",tmpString,noSpaces];

NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mysite.com/contacts.php" ] ]; 
[ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
[ request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
[ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];    
NSData *stringReplys = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];


contactprogress.progress = 1;   
StatusLabel.text = @"Status: Complete";
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:stringReplys
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];   
[alert release];
```

tmpStrings is just a number phone number like = 07919327368 and noSpaces is a list of contacts and numbers formatted with no spaces i cannot see why this would not work ?

I know the php is fine as i can send post's via my pc

Thank you

Mason

Could it be that the data is too large

Comment: I keep recieving the SIGABRT signal :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the ALERT it couldnt show stringReplys as it is a Data have to convert to string using this  :S

```
stringReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that seems wrong is that you have:

```
[ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
```

and I believe you want to use:

```
[ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

I'm not sure if the `Content-Type` is getting set automatically by some other call, but that could cause a problem with the data not being decoded correctly.

Comment: i fixed it the problems was the ALERT